# Heroku Could not find or load main class in java

Tags: java, rest, heroku, jax-rs

I'm using heroku with maven to run a server!
With the server setup running locally I can test my REST resource:
Start the server by running the following command:

> mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.App" and then :
>
> curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/resources
>   ---> it returns the response as Json.

now i would like to deploy my application to heroku! before this i can test it locally using Heroku but i get an error :

> mvn clean package
>
> heroku local web
>   --->Error: the main class com.App could not be found
>   --->Exited with exit code 1

my Procfile: web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.App
my project's structure: src->main->java->com-->App

Any idea what could be the reason of this error ?

Comment: have you tried running the app locally with `java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.App`?

Comment: if I run this on CMD "java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.App" I got the same Error: the main class com.App could not be found

Comment: Does target/classes contain your class?

Comment: yes it contains my class